# Adding quota to users in Collaborative Forecasts

Tags: forecast, forecasts-collaborative, quota

How can I add a quota to users in Collaborative Forecasts.

Answer (score 1):

In the AppExchange, Salesforce labs has made available a free package to help with this: Edit Quotas.
It creates an extra tab that allows you to enter quotas for users, for periods, manually. Much easier to use than Data Loader.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload quotas to the RevenueForecast object via the Data Loader.  Features coming in Spring14 may change that.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, @Aiden.  Could you flesh out this response with a link to the documentation (for a previous release, likely) explaining how to set quotas?

Comment: @Aiden I'm using the workbench and I do not see this object (RevenueForecast)